# calculating the expected value of a random variable on two different domains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

i have some information about the CDF of a random variable X.

when $0 \le x < 3$:

$F(x) = \frac{1}{9}(2 x^2 - \frac{x^3}{3})$

when $x \ge 3$:

$F(x) = 1$

i need to calculate the expected value of this variable.

it seems like i need to calculate two integrals: one for the first domain using $x \cdot f(x)$ and one for the second domain (3 to infinity) using the same definition of $f(x)$, but not multiplying by x.

but when i calculate the value of this second integral, it's divergent.

what am i doing wrong? any suggestions? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the CDF for the denisty. The density is $F'$ which is $0$ for $x \geq 3$. So the expected value is just $\int_0^{3} \frac d {dx} \frac 1 9 (2x^{2}-\frac {x^{3}} 3)dx=1$.

Comment: so i don't use $F'=f$ here?

Comment: @qwerty Sorry, I have edited.